# Copy first row values to all rows and update two columns value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-update

We have a table where the first row will be updated with UI input through API, we have to replicate the same data for different dates from another table.
How do we do it in SQL (working on SQL Server 2019)?

Table 1 (source table which needs to be updated) where ID is a Identity column

| ID | capId | date | col1 | col2 | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 7/3/2022 | 40 | 120 | 0 |

values for dates and volume column should be fetched from table 2 as below:

| capId | date | volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 7/3/2022 | 0 |
| 2 | 7/10/2022 | 123 |
| 2 | 7/17/2022 | 456 |
| 2 | 7/24/2022 | 789 |
| 2 | 7/31/2022 | 2975 |

I want the table 1 to be like:

| ID | capId | date | col1 | col2 | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 7/3/2022 | 40 | 120 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 7/10/2022 | 40 | 120 | 123 |
| 3 | 2 | 7/17/2022 | 40 | 120 | 456 |
| 4 | 2 | 7/24/2022 | 40 | 120 | 789 |
| 5 | 2 | 7/31/2022 | 40 | 120 | 2975 |

I have tried below query to add in the date and volume from table2 but stuck in copying the top row to add other rows:

```
insert into table1 (capId, [date], volume)
(
   select a.capId AS capId,
      a.[date] AS [date] , a.volume AS volume,
   from
   (
      Select s.*,
         row_number() over(order by [date]) rn
      from table2 s
      where capId = 2
   ) a
   where rn >1
)
```

How do we do this in SQL?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this just a `JOIN` on `CapId`?

Comment: why are you inserting from table2 into table1? what happens if the data in table2 later changes but you've already copied it into table1?

Comment: @RickyTillson, Table2 data is fixed data. I want to copy the dates to Table1, as there are further operations happening on table1 with reference to date column

Comment: You know SQL databases don't have a concept of a "first row", right? Tables are defined as **unordered** sets; this is baked into the concept of a relational database. SQL databases do not track which row is inserted first and are free to re-order records on disk to improve performance based on things like statistics and primary keys

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I am aware of the above point. I first row i have mentioned is the first row in the grouping by capid.

Answer (score 1):

The Schema should be changed.
The second table does not contain a primary key, and you should not duplicate data, So You should do the following changes to your table's schema.

First table:

| ID | CapId | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Table two:

| capId | date | volume |
| --- | --- | --- |

The capId should be unique(primary key), and then add a foreign key constraint into the first table.

Then your insert script:

1. Insert new values into the second table

```sql
insert into table2 values (date, volume);
```

2. Get the last fetched ID from the second table and store it as a variable:

```sql
SELECT MAX(capId) AS LastID FROM table2;
```

3. insert new values into tabel1:

```sql
insert into table1 values(LastID, col1, col2);
```

Even if the data in the second table is fixed, in this way you just need to attach your new row in the first table with the corresponding capId from the second table

```sql
insert into table1 values(capID, col1, col2);
```